# PyTorch reshape tensor dimension

Tags: python, pytorch, reshape, tensor

I want to reshape a vector of shape `(5,)` into a matrix of shape `(1, 5)`.

With numpy, I can do:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a.shape
(5,)
>>> a = np.reshape(a, (1, 5))
>>> a.shape
(1, 5)
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

But how do I do this with PyTorch?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use  [`torch.unsqueeze(input, dim, out=None)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html#torch.unsqueeze):

```
>>> import torch
>>> a = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> a

 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
[torch.FloatTensor of size 5]

>>> a = a.unsqueeze(0)
>>> a

 1  2  3  4  5
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x5]
```

Answer (score 23):

you might use

```
a.view(1,5)
Out: 

 1  2  3  4  5
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x5]
```

Comment: Note that this **does not** modify the original tensor `a`. It just creates a view.

Answer (score 21):

There are multiple ways of reshaping a PyTorch tensor. You can apply these methods on a tensor of any dimensionality.

Let's start with a 2-dimensional `2 x 3` tensor:

```
x = torch.Tensor(2, 3)
print(x.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 3])
```

**To add some robustness to this problem, let's reshape the `2 x 3` tensor by adding a new dimension at the front and another dimension in the middle, producing a `1 x 2 x 1 x 3` tensor.**

### Approach 1: add dimension with `None`

Use NumPy-style [insertion of `None` (aka `np.newaxis`) to add dimensions](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.1.10) anywhere you want. See [here](https://mlpipes.com/adding-a-dimension-to-a-tensor-in-pytorch/).

```
print(x.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 3])

y = x[None, :, None, :] # Add new dimensions at positions 0 and 2.
print(y.shape)
# torch.Size([1, 2, 1, 3])
```

### Approach 2: unsqueeze

Use [`torch.Tensor.unsqueeze(i)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.unsqueeze) (a.k.a. [`torch.unsqueeze(tensor, i)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.unsqueeze) or the in-place version `unsqueeze_()`) to add a new dimension at the i'th dimension. The returned tensor shares the same data as the original tensor. In this example, we can use `unqueeze()` twice to add the two new dimensions.

```
print(x.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 3])

# Use unsqueeze twice.
y = x.unsqueeze(0) # Add new dimension at position 0
print(y.shape)
# torch.Size([1, 2, 3])

y = y.unsqueeze(2) # Add new dimension at position 2
print(y.shape)
# torch.Size([1, 2, 1, 3])
```

In practice with PyTorch, [adding an extra dimension for the batch](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-add-a-batch-dimension-in-my-picture/21141/2) may be important, so you may often see `unsqueeze(0)`.

### Approach 3: view

Use [`torch.Tensor.view(*shape)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view) to specify all the dimensions. The returned tensor shares the same data as the original tensor.

```
print(x.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 3])

y = x.view(1, 2, 1, 3)
print(y.shape)
# torch.Size([1, 2, 1, 3])
```

### Approach 4: reshape

Use [`torch.Tensor.reshape(*shape)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.reshape) (aka [`torch.reshape(tensor, shapetuple)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.reshape)) to specify all the dimensions. If the original data is contiguous and has the same stride, the returned tensor will be a view of input (sharing the same data), otherwise it will be a copy. This function is similar to the NumPy [`reshape()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) function in that it lets you define all the dimensions and can return either a view or a copy.

```
print(x.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 3])

y = x.reshape(1, 2, 1, 3)
print(y.shape)
# torch.Size([1, 2, 1, 3])
```

Furthermore, from the O'Reilly 2019 book [Programming PyTorch for Deep Learning](https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-pytorch-for/9781492045342/), the author writes:

*Now you might wonder what the difference is between `view()` and `reshape()`. The answer is that `view()` operates as a view on the original tensor, so if the underlying data is changed, the view will change too (and vice versa). However, `view()` can throw errors if the required view is not contiguous; that is, it doesn’t share the same block of memory it would occupy if a new tensor of the required shape was created from scratch. If this happens, you have to call `tensor.contiguous()` before you can use `view()`. However, `reshape()` does all that behind the scenes, so in general, I recommend using `reshape()` rather than `view()`.*

### Approach 5: resize_

Use the in-place function [`torch.Tensor.resize_(*sizes)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.resize_) to modify the original tensor. The documentation states:

*WARNING. This is a low-level method. The storage is reinterpreted as C-contiguous, ignoring the current strides (unless the target size equals the current size, in which case the tensor is left unchanged). For most purposes, you will instead want to use `view()`, which checks for contiguity, or `reshape()`, which copies data if needed. To change the size in-place with custom strides, see `set_()`.*

```
print(x.shape)
# torch.Size([2, 3])

x.resize_(1, 2, 1, 3)
print(x.shape)
# torch.Size([1, 2, 1, 3])
```

### My observations

If you want to add just one dimension (e.g. to add a 0th dimension for the batch), then use `unsqueeze(0)`. If you want to totally change the dimensionality, use `reshape()`.

### See also:

[What's the difference between reshape and view in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643225/whats-the-difference-between-reshape-and-view-in-pytorch)

[What is the difference between view() and unsqueeze()?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-difference-between-view-and-unsqueeze/1155)

[In PyTorch 0.4, is it recommended to use `reshape` than `view` when it is possible?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/in-pytorch-0-4-is-it-recommended-to-use-reshape-than-view-when-it-is-possible/17034)

Answer (score 16):

For *in-place* modification of the shape of the tensor, you should use 
 [**`tensor.resize_()`**](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.resize_):

```
In [23]: a = torch.Tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [24]: a.shape
Out[24]: torch.Size([5])


# tensor.resize_((`new_shape`))    
In [25]: a.resize_((1,5))
Out[25]: 

 1  2  3  4  5
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x5]

In [26]: a.shape
Out[26]: torch.Size([1, 5])
```

In PyTorch, if there's an underscore at the end of an operation (like `tensor.resize_()`) then that operation does `in-place` modification to the original tensor.

---

Also, you can simply use `np.newaxis` in a torch Tensor to increase the dimension. Here is an example:

```
In [34]: list_ = range(5)
In [35]: a = torch.Tensor(list_)
In [36]: a.shape
Out[36]: torch.Size([5])

In [37]: new_a = a[np.newaxis, :]
In [38]: new_a.shape
Out[38]: torch.Size([1, 5])
```

Answer (score 6):

or you can use this, the '-1' means you don't have to specify the number of the elements.

```
In [3]: a.view(1,-1)
Out[3]:

 1  2  3  4  5
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x5]
```

Answer (score 6):

This question has been thoroughly answered already, but I want to add for the less experienced python developers that you might find the `*` operator helpful in conjunction with `view()`.

For example if you have a particular tensor size that you want a different tensor of data to conform to, you might try:

```
img = Variable(tensor.randn(20,30,3)) # tensor with goal shape
flat_size = 20*30*3
X = Variable(tensor.randn(50, flat_size)) # data tensor

X = X.view(-1, *img.size()) # sweet maneuver
print(X.size()) # size is (50, 20, 30, 3)
```

This works with numpy `shape` too:

```
img = np.random.randn(20,30,3)
flat_size = 20*30*3
X = Variable(tensor.randn(50, flat_size))
X = X.view(-1, *img.shape)
print(X.size()) # size is (50, 20, 30, 3)
```

Answer (score 5):

[torch.reshape()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html) is made to dupe the [numpy reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) method.

It came after the [view()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_view.html) and [torch.resize_()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.resize_) and it is inside the `dir(torch)` package.

```
import torch
x=torch.arange(24)
print(x, x.shape)
x_view = x.view(1,2,3,4) # works on is_contiguous() tensor
print(x_view.shape)
x_reshaped = x.reshape(1,2,3,4) # works on any tensor
print(x_reshaped.shape)
x_reshaped2 = torch.reshape(x_reshaped, (-1,)) # part of torch package, while view() and resize_() are not
print(x_reshaped2.shape)
```

Out:

```
tensor([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
        18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]) torch.Size([24])
torch.Size([1, 2, 3, 4])
torch.Size([1, 2, 3, 4])
torch.Size([24])
```

But did you know it can also work as a replacement for [squeeze()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.squeeze.html) and [unsqueeze()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html)

```
x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(x.shape)
x1 = torch.unsqueeze(x, 0)
print(x1.shape)
x2 = torch.unsqueeze(x1, 1)
print(x2.shape)
x3=x.reshape(1,1,4)
print(x3.shape)
x4=x.reshape(4)
print(x4.shape)
x5=x3.squeeze()
print(x5.shape)
```

Out:

```
torch.Size([4])
torch.Size([1, 4])
torch.Size([1, 1, 4])
torch.Size([1, 1, 4])
torch.Size([4])
torch.Size([4])
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the best way to reshape tensors is to use `einops`. It solves various reshape problems by providing a simple and elegant function. In your situation, the code could be written as

```py
from einops import rearrange
ans = rearrange(tensor,'h -> 1 h')
```

I highly recommend you try it.

BTW, you can use it with pytorch/tensorflow/numpy and many other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

```
import torch
>>>a = torch.Tensor([1,2,3,4,5])
>>>a.size()
torch.Size([5])
#use view to reshape

>>>b = a.view(1,a.shape[0])
>>>b
tensor([[1., 2., 3., 4., 5.]])
>>>b.size()
torch.Size([1, 5])
>>>b.type()
'torch.FloatTensor'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the following code:

```
import torch
import numpy as np
a = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

The following three calls have the exact same effect:

```
res_1 = a.unsqueeze(0)
res_2 = a.view(1, 5)
res_3 = a[np.newaxis,:]
res_1.shape == res_2.shape == res_3.shape == (1,5)  # Returns true
```

Notice that for any of the resulting tensors, if you modify the data in them, you are also modifying the data in a, because they don't have a copy of the data, but reference the original data in a.

```
res_1[0,0] = 2
a[0] == res_1[0,0] == 2  # Returns true
```

The other way of doing it would be using the `resize_` in place operation:

```
a.shape == res_1.shape  # Returns false
a.reshape_((1, 5))
a.shape == res_1.shape # Returns true
```

Be careful of using `resize_` or other in-place operation with `autograd`.  See the following discussion: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#in-place-operations-with-autograd

Comment: You state *The other way of doing it would be using the resize_ in place operation*, but your code uses `reshape_`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import torch
t = torch.ones((2, 3, 4))
t.size()
```

```
>>torch.Size([2, 3, 4])
```

```
a = t.view(-1,t.size()[1]*t.size()[2])
a.size()
```

```
>>torch.Size([2, 12])
```