# What's the difference between reshape and view in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

In numpy, we use `ndarray.reshape()` for reshaping an array.

I noticed that in pytorch, people use `torch.view(...)` for the same purpose, but at the same time, there is also a `torch.reshape(...)` existing.

So I am wondering what the differences are between them and when I should use either of them?

Answer (score 254, accepted):

`torch.view` has existed for a long time. It will return a tensor with the new shape. The returned tensor will share the underling data with the original tensor. 
See the [documentation here](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html?highlight=view#torch.Tensor.view).

On the other hand, it seems that `torch.reshape` [has been introduced recently in version 0.4](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/5575). According to the [document](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.reshape), this method will

> Returns a tensor with the same data and number of elements as input, but with the specified shape. When possible, the returned tensor will be a view of input. Otherwise, it will be a copy. Contiguous inputs and inputs with compatible strides can be reshaped without copying, but you should not depend on the copying vs. viewing behavior.

It means that `torch.reshape` may return a copy or a view of the original tensor. You can not count on that to return a view or a copy. According to the developer:

> if you need a copy use clone() if you need the same storage use view(). The semantics of reshape() are that it may or may not share the storage and you don't know beforehand.

Another difference is that `reshape()` can operate on both contiguous and non-contiguous tensor while `view()` can only operate on contiguous tensor. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26999092/6064933) about the meaning of `contiguous`.

Comment: Maybe emphasizing that torch.view can only operate on contiguous tensors, while torch.reshape can operate on both might be helpful too.

Comment: @pierrom contiguous here referring to tensors that are stored in contiguous memory or something else?

Comment: @gokul_uf Yes, you can take a look at the answer written here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915810/pytorch-contiguous

Comment: does the phrase "a view of a tensor" mean in pytorch?

Comment: It will be helpful to have an explanation on what is "compatible strides". Thanks!

Comment: when does one use `.view` vs `.shape`?

Comment: view() _can_ operate on non-contiguous tensors. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @pierrom No, I think MBT's comment can be a bit confusing. the expression `contiguous` here does **not** mean whether the data is stored in contiguous memory blocks or not. Even if a pytorch tensor is not "contiguous", the elements are arranged in contiguous memory blocks. The expression "contiguous" here is related to the order of the elements when pytorch see the tensor.

Comment: This should be corrected: *"The semantics of reshape() are that it may or may not share the storage and you don't know beforehand."* => you are able to **Know** beforehand. It's *not* a random operation between sharing or not sharing the storage.

Comment: This answer is clear and straight to the point, but it is too bad it can easily be missed because of other long answers shown above it.

Answer (score 100):

Although both `torch.view` and `torch.reshape` are used to reshape tensors, here are the differences between them.

1. As the name suggests, `torch.view` merely creates a *view* of the original tensor. The new tensor will *always* share its data with the original tensor. This means that if you change the original tensor, the reshaped tensor will change and vice versa.

```py
>>> z = torch.zeros(3, 2)
>>> x = z.view(2, 3)
>>> z.fill_(1)
>>> x
tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])
```

2. To ensure that the new tensor always shares its data with the original, `torch.view` imposes some contiguity constraints on the shapes of the two tensors [[docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view)]. More often than not this is not a concern, but sometimes `torch.view` throws an error even if the shapes of the two tensors are compatible. Here's a famous counter-example.

```py
>>> z = torch.zeros(3, 2)
>>> y = z.t()
>>> y.size()
torch.Size([2, 3])
>>> y.view(6)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: invalid argument 2: view size is not compatible with input tensor's
size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces).
Call .contiguous() before .view().
```

3. `torch.reshape` doesn't impose any contiguity constraints, but also doesn't guarantee data sharing. The new tensor may be a view of the original tensor, or it may be a new tensor altogether.

```py
>>> z = torch.zeros(3, 2)
>>> y = z.reshape(6)
>>> x = z.t().reshape(6)
>>> z.fill_(1)
tensor([[1., 1.],
        [1., 1.],
        [1., 1.]])
>>> y
tensor([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.])
>>> x
tensor([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

**TL;DR:**
If you just want to reshape tensors, use `torch.reshape`. If you're also concerned about memory usage and want to ensure that the two tensors share the same data, use `torch.view`.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I was confused into thinking that contiguity is the deciding factor between when reshape does and does not share data.  From my own experiments, it seems that this is not the case.  (Your `x` and `y` above are both contiguous).

Perhaps this can be clarified?  Perhaps a comment on _when_ reshape does and does not copy would be helpful?

Comment: `x` and `y` are contiguous but we care here about `z` and `z.t()`. `z`is contiguous so `y` and `z` share the same data. `z` and `z.t()` share the same data, but `z.t()` is not contiguous so `z.t()` and `x` do not share the same data. Therefore `x` and `y` do not share the same data.

Answer (score 42):

view() will try to change the shape of the tensor while keeping the underlying data allocation the same, thus data will be shared between the two tensors. reshape() will create a new underlying memory allocation if necessary.

Let's create a tensor:

```
a = torch.arange(8).reshape(2, 4)
```

[image: initial 2D tensor]

The memory is allocated like below (it is *C contiguous* i.e. the rows are stored next to each other):

[image: initial 2D tensor's memory allocation]

stride() gives the number of bytes required to go to the next element in each dimension:

```
a.stride()
(4, 1)
```

We want its shape to become (4, 2), we can use view:

```
a.view(4,2)
```

[image: after view to switch the dimensions]

The underlying data allocation has not changed, the tensor is still *C contiguous*:

[image: memory allocation after switch]

```
a.view(4, 2).stride()
(2, 1)
```

Let's try with a.t(). Transpose() doesn't modify the underlying memory allocation and therefore a.t() is not contiguous.

```
a.t().is_contiguous()
False
```

[image: after transpose]

[image: memory allocation after transpose]

Although it is not contiguous, the stride information is sufficient to iterate over the tensor

```
a.t().stride()
(1, 4)
```

view() doesn't work anymore:

```
a.t().view(2, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: view size is not compatible with input tensor's size and stride (at least one dimension spans across two contiguous subspaces). Use .reshape(...) instead.
```

Below is the shape we wanted to obtain by using view(2, 4):

[image: after transpose and reshape]

What would the memory allocation look like?

[image: memory allocation without reshape]

The stride would be something like (2, 4) but we would have to go back to the begining of the tensor after we reach the end. It doesn't work.

In this case, reshape() would create a new tensor with a different memory allocation to make the transpose contiguous:

[image: memory allocation with reshape or contiguous]

Note that we can use view to split the first dimension of the transpose.
Unlike what is said in the accepted and other answers, view() can operate on non-contiguous tensors!

```
a.t().view(2, 2, 2)
```

[image: after transpose and view 2, 2, 2]

[image: memory allocation after transpose]

```
a.t().view(2, 2, 2).stride()
(2, 1, 4)
```

[According to the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html#torch.Tensor.view):

> For a tensor to be viewed, the new view size must be compatible with
> its original size and stride, i.e., each new view dimension must
> either be a subspace of an original dimension, or only span across
> original dimensions d, d+1, …, d+k that satisfy the following
> contiguity-like condition that ∀i=d,…,d+k−1,
> stride[i]=stride[i+1]×size[i+1]

Here that's because the first two dimensions after applying view(2, 2, 2) are subspaces of the transpose's first dimension.

For more information about contiguity have a look at my answer [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69599806/4815835)

Comment: The illustration and its color darkness help me understand what `contiguous` means, it means whether indexing all of next number in one row is contiguous or not. BTW, there is a minor typo at `b.t().is_contiguous()`, it might  be  `a.t().is_contiguous()`, thanks all the same !

Comment: Thanks for your comment and for catching the typo! It's now fixed.

Comment: "The stride would be something like (4, 2)" - it should be (2, 4), right?

Comment: "but we would have to go back to the begining of the tensor after we reach the end" - if there would be a modulo operation (mod the num elems), then such stride should be correct, right? I wonder if it might make sense to allow for that.

Comment: Yes you're right. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

`Tensor.reshape()` is more robust. It will work on any tensor, while `Tensor.view()` works only on tensor `t` where `t.is_contiguous()==True`.

To explain about non-contiguous and contiguous is another story, but you can always make the tensor `t` contiguous if you call `t.contiguous()` and then you can call `view()` without the error.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the answers here are technically correct but there's another reason for existing of `reshape`. `pytorch` is usually considered more convenient than other frameworks because it closer to `python` and `numpy`. It's interesting that the question involves `numpy`.

Let's look into `size` and `shape` in `pytorch`. `size` is a function so you call it like `x.size()`. `shape` in `pytorch` is not a function. In `numpy` you have `shape` and it's *not* a function - you use it `x.shape`. So it's handy to get both of them in `pytorch`. If you came from `numpy` it would be nice to use the same functions.