# In PyTorch, what makes a tensor have non-contiguous memory?

Tags: pytorch

According to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643225) and [this PyTorch discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/in-pytorch-0-4-is-it-recommended-to-use-reshape-than-view-when-it-is-possible/17034/2), PyTorch's `view` function works only on contiguous memory, while `reshape` does not. In the second link, the author even claims:

> [`view`] will raise an error on a non-contiguous tensor.

But when does a tensor have non-contiguous memory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26999092/4280242) is a very good answer, which explains the topic in the context of NumPy. PyTorch works essentially the same. Its docs don't generally mention whether function outputs are (non)contiguous, but that's something that can be guessed based on the kind of the operation (with some experience and understanding of the implementation). As a rule of thumb, most operations preserve contiguity as they *construct* new tensors. You may see non-contiguous outputs if the operation works on the array inplace and change its striding. A couple of examples below

```
import torch

t = torch.randn(10, 10)

def check(ten):
    print(ten.is_contiguous())

check(t) # True

# flip sets the stride to negative, but element j is still adjacent to
# element i, so it is contiguous
check(torch.flip(t, (0,))) # True

# if we take every 2nd element, adjacent elements in the resulting array
# are not adjacent in the input array
check(t[::2]) # False

# if we transpose, we lose contiguity, as in case of NumPy
check(t.transpose(0, 1)) # False

# if we transpose twice, we first lose and then regain contiguity
check(t.transpose(0, 1).transpose(0, 1)) # True
```

In general, if you have non-contiguous tensor `t`, you can make it contiguous by calling `t = t.contiguous()`. If `t` is contiguous, call to `t.contiguous()` is essentially a no-op, so you can do that without risking a big performance hit.

Answer (score 4):

I think your title `contiguous memory` is a bit misleading. As I understand, `contiguous` in PyTorch means if the neighboring elements in the tensor are actually next to each other in memory. Let's take a simple example:

```py
x = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]) # x is contiguous
y = torch.transpose(0, 1) # y is non-contiguous
```

According to [documentation of `tranpose()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.transpose):

> Returns a tensor that is a transposed version of input. The given dimensions dim0 and dim1 are swapped.
>
> **The resulting out tensor shares it’s underlying storage with the input tensor**, so changing the content of one would change the content of the other.

So that `x` and `y` in the above example **share the same memory space**. But if you check their contiguity with `is_contiguous()`, you will find that `x` is contiguous and `y` is not. Now you will find that `contiguity` does not refer to `contiguous memory`.

Since `x` is contiguous, `x[0][0]` and `x[0][1]` are next to each other in memory. But `y[0][0]` and `y[0][1]` is not. That is what `contiguous` means.