# Can tensor in Tensorflow have non-contigous memory?

Tags: tensorflow, memory, gpu, cudnn

Tensors in PyTorch can have non-contiguous memory, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095351/in-pytorch-what-makes-a-tensor-have-non-contiguous-memory).

What about Tensorflow? Can tensors in Tensorflow have non-contiguous memory? Or is it impossible because of static graph?