# How do I flatten a tensor in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Given a tensor of multiple dimensions, how do I flatten it so that it has a ***single*** dimension?

```
torch.Size([2, 3, 5])    ⟶ flatten ⟶    torch.Size([30])
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

#### TL;DR: `torch.flatten()`

Use [`torch.flatten()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.flatten) which was introduced in [v0.4.1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v0.4.1) and documented in [v1.0rc1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases/tag/v1.0rc1):

> ```
> >>> t = torch.tensor([[[1, 2],
>                        [3, 4]],
>                       [[5, 6],
>                        [7, 8]]])
> >>> torch.flatten(t)
> tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
> >>> torch.flatten(t, start_dim=1)
> tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4],
>         [5, 6, 7, 8]])
> ```

For v0.4.1 and earlier, use [`t.reshape(-1)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.reshape).

---

With `t.reshape(-1)`:

If the requested view is contiguous in memory
this will equivalent to [`t.view(-1)`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html?highlight=view#torch.Tensor.view) and memory will not be copied.

Otherwise it will be equivalent to `t.`[`contiguous()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.contiguous)`.view(-1)`.

---

Other non-options:

- `t.view(-1)` [won't copy memory, but may not work depending on original size and stride](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html?highlight=view#torch.Tensor.view)
- `t.resize(-1)` gives `RuntimeError` (see below)
- `t.resize(t.numel())` [warning about being a low-level method](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.resize_)
  (see discussion below)

(Note: `pytorch`'s `reshape()` may change data but [`numpy`'s `reshape()` won't](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).)

---

`t.resize(t.numel())` needs some discussion. The [`torch.Tensor.resize_` documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.resize_) says:

> The storage is reinterpreted as C-contiguous, ignoring the current strides (unless the target size equals the current size, in which case the tensor is left unchanged)

Given the current strides will be ignored with the new `(1, numel())` size, the order of the elements *may* apppear in a different order than with `reshape(-1)`. However, "size" *may* mean the memory size, rather than the tensor's size.

It would be nice if `t.resize(-1)` worked for both convenience and efficiency, but with `torch 1.0.1.post2`, `t = torch.rand([2, 3, 5]);  t.resize(-1)` gives:

```
RuntimeError: requested resize to -1 (-1 elements in total), but the given 
tensor has a size of 2x2 (4 elements). autograd's resize can only change the 
shape of a given tensor, while preserving the number of elements.
```

I raised a feature request for this [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/18984), but the consensus was that `resize()` was a low level method, and `reshape()` should be used in preference.

Comment: You can just specify `-1`. The `squeeze` op is not really necessary.

Comment: `reshape` can do that.

Comment: `reshape()` may return a copy or a view of the original tensor. Doco link in answer above.

Comment: torch.flatten(var, start_dim=1), the start_dim parameter is great.

Answer (score 15):

Use `torch.reshape` and only a single dimension can be passed to flatten it. If you do not want the dimension to be hardcoded, just `-1` could be specified and the correct dimension would be inferred.

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[1,2], [3,4]])
>>> x.reshape(-1)
tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

EDIT:

For your example:
[image]

Comment: Fails with `torch.rand([2, 3, 5])`. See my answer for the output.

Comment: @TomHale Please take a look at the attached screenshot. Don't understand the reason for downvote instead of a simple nudge.

Comment: Mine uses `reshape`

Comment: Note that `reshape()` **always** copies memory.

Comment: Not always the case as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49644300/1849998)

Answer (score 5):

`flatten()` uses `reshape()` beneath in [C++ PyTorch code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/ef6356133ebdc4b9b49dd1aac2ca7b3e3f05ca7c/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp#L814-L839).

With `flatten()` you may do things like this:

```py
import torch
input = torch.rand(2, 3, 4).cuda()
print(input.shape) # torch.Size([2, 3, 4])
print(input.flatten(start_dim=0, end_dim=1).shape) # torch.Size([6, 4])
```

while for the same *flattening* if you would like to use `reshape` you would do:

```py
print(input.reshape((6,4)).shape) # torch.Size([6, 4])
```

But usually you would just do simple flatten like this:

```py
print(input.reshape(-1).shape) # torch.Size([24])
print(input.flatten().shape) # torch.Size([24])
```

Note:

> `reshape()` is more robust than `view()`. It will work on any tensor, while `view()` works only on tensor `t` where `t.is_contiguous()==True`.

Answer (score 3):

you can do a simple `t.view(-1)`

```
>>>t = torch.rand([2, 3, 5])
>>>t = t.view(-1)
>>>t.shape
torch.Size([30])
```