# Torchvision.transforms implementation of Flatten()

Tags: python, pytorch, flatten, torchvision

I have grayscale images, but I need transform it to a dataset of 1d vectors
How can I do this? I could not find a suitable method in transforms:

```py
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root='./data',train=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
test_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root='./data',train=False, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Do you mean `flatten`?

Comment: @Berriel 
Yes. How i can do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I flatten a tensor in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55546873/how-do-i-flatten-a-tensor-in-pytorch)

Comment: @Berriel  Thank you, but not really.
transforms.ToTensor returns Tensor, but I can't write in ImageFolder function         

'transform = torch.flatten(transforms.ToTensor())'          

and  it         

'transform=transforms.LinearTransformation(transforms.ToTensor(),torch.zeros(1,784))'
              
         Maybe, it solved by transforms.Compose, but I don't know how

Comment: Check my answer. You used `torch.flatten` in the wrong way. You "have" to use Compose and I used it in my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how you can do it using `Lambda`

```py
import torch
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
import torchvision.transforms as T

# without flatten
dataset = MNIST(root='.', download=True, transform=T.ToTensor())
print(dataset[0][0].shape)
# >>> torch.Size([1, 28, 28])

# with flatten (using Lambda, but you can do it in many other ways)
dataset_flatten = MNIST(root='.', download=True, transform=T.Compose([T.ToTensor(), T.Lambda(lambda x: torch.flatten(x))]))
print(dataset_flatten[0][0].shape)
# >>> torch.Size([784])
```

Comment: Is it a good practice to do this operation in the transform section?

Comment: @Opsse I wouldn't say good practice, but I'd rather consider this op part of my data processing pipeline than of my model; therefore I'd use it there.

Answer (score 2):

The `lambda` seems to be unnecessary, and will raise a [PyLint unnecessary-lambda / W0108 warning](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/messages/warning/unnecessary-lambda.html).

This version of @Berriel's solution is thus more precise:

```
import torch
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
import torchvision.transforms as T

# without flatten
dataset = MNIST(root='.', download=True, transform=T.ToTensor())
print(dataset[0][0].shape)
# >>> torch.Size([1, 28, 28])

# with flatten (using Lambda, but you can do it in many other ways)
dataset_flatten = MNIST(root='.', download=True,
    transform=T.Compose([T.ToTensor(), T.Lambda(torch.flatten)]))
print(dataset_flatten[0][0].shape)
# >>> torch.Size([784])
```

Comment: I think even `T.Lambda(torch.flatten)` is unnecessary, and you can just replace it with `torch.flatten`, IE `dataset_flatten = torchvision.datasets.MNIST('./data', download=True, transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose( [torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(), torch.flatten]))` ? Works for me at least, Python 3.7.6 and PyTorch version 1.13.0+cu117