# How can I unroll a PyTorch Tensor?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor:

```
t1 = torch.randn(564, 400)
```

I want to unroll it to a 1-d tensor that's `225600` long.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I flatten a tensor in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55546873/how-do-i-flatten-a-tensor-in-pytorch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the difference between `view` and `reshape` as suggested by Kris -
From `reshape`'s docstring:

> When possible, the returned tensor will be a view
> of `input`. Otherwise, it will be a copy. Contiguous inputs and inputs with compatible strides can be reshaped without copying...

So in case your tensor is not contiguous calling `reshape` should handle what one would have had to handle had one used `view` instead; That is, call `t1.contiguous().view(...)` to handle non-contiguous tensors.

Also, one could use `faltten`: `t1 = t1.flatten()` as an equivalent of `view(-1)`, which is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Pytorch is much like numpy so you can simply do,

```
t1 = t1.view(-1) or t1 = t1.reshape(-1)
```