# Different `grad_fn` for similar looking operations in Pytorch (1.0)

Tags: python, pytorch, attention-model

I am working on an attention model, and before running the final model, I was going through the tensor shapes which flow through the code. I have an operation where I need to reshape the tensor. The tensor is of the shape `torch.Size([[30, 8, 9, 64]])`  where `30` is the `batch_size`, `8` is the number of attention head (this is not relevant to my question) `9` is the number of words in the sentence and `64` is some intermediate embedding representation of the word. I have to reshape the tensor to a size of `torch.size([30, 9, 512])` before processing it further. So I was looking into some reference online and they have done the following `x.transpose(1, 2).contiguous().view(30, -1, 512)`
whereas I was thinking that this should work `x.transpose(1, 2).reshape(30, -1, 512)`.

In the first case the `grad_fn` is `<ViewBackward>`, whereas in my case it is `<UnsafeViewBackward>`. Aren't these two the same operations? Will this result in a training error?

Comment: two operations are different so that you get different `grad_fn`. Visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643225/whats-the-difference-between-reshape-and-view-in-pytorch) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

> Aren't these two the same operations?

No. While they produce effectively the same tensor, the operations [are not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643225/whats-the-difference-between-reshape-and-view-in-pytorch), and they are not guaranteed to have the same `storage`.

[TensorShape.cpp](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/af64789cfa3aef37926fb3d9601d5e47406098c8/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp#L959):

```c
// _unsafe_view() differs from view() in that the returned tensor isn't treated
// as a view for the purposes of automatic differentiation. (It's not listed in
// VIEW_FUNCTIONS in gen_autograd.py).  It's only safe to use if the `self` tensor
// is temporary. For example, the viewed tensor here (a + b) is discarded immediately
// after viewing:
//
//  res = at::_unsafe_view(a + b, size);
//
// This is a hack because in-place operations on tensors treated like views
// can be much more expensive than the same operations on non-view tensors.
```

Note this *can* produce an error if applied to [complex inputs](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/unsafeviewbackward-in-grad-fn/25992/10?u=iacob), but this is generally not yet fully supported in PyTorch and not unique to this function.