# What is the difference between .flatten() and .view(-1) in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

Both `.flatten()` and `.view(-1)` flatten a tensor in PyTorch. What's the difference?

1. Does `.flatten()` copy the data of the tensor?
2. Is `.view(-1)` faster?
3. Is there any situation that `.flatten()` doesn't work?

Comment: I think they are identical for the default arguments to `.flatten()`, but `.flatten()` allows you to pass a `start_dim` and an `end_dim` to get more complex behavior. For example, `torch.ones(10, 4, 5, 6).flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=2)` returns a tensor of shape `(10, 20, 6)`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In addition to @adeelh's comment, there is another difference: `torch.flatten()` results in a `.reshape()`, and the [differences between `.reshape()` and `.view()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49644300/4228275) are:

> - [...] `torch.reshape` may return a copy or a view of the original tensor. You can not count on that to return a view or a copy.
> - Another difference is that reshape() can operate on both contiguous and non-contiguous tensor while view() can only operate on contiguous tensor. Also see here about the meaning of contiguous

For context:

- The community requested for a `flatten` function for a while, and after [Issue #7743](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7743), the feature was implemented in the [PR #8578](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/8578).
- You can see the implementation of flatten [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/ef6356133ebdc4b9b49dd1aac2ca7b3e3f05ca7c/aten/src/ATen/native/TensorShape.cpp#L814-L839), where a call to `.reshape()` can be seen in `return` line.

Answer (score 15):

`flatten` is simply a [convenient alias](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_view.html) of a common use-case of `view`.<sup>1</sup>

There are several others:

| Function | Equivalent `view` logic |
| --- | --- |
| `flatten()` | `view(-1)` |
| `flatten(start, end)` | `view(*t.shape[:start], -1, *t.shape[end+1:])` |
| `squeeze()` | `view(*[s for s in t.shape if s != 1])` |
| `unsqueeze(i)` | `view(*t.shape[:i-1], 1, *t.shape[i:])` |

Note that `flatten` allows you to flatten a specific contiguous subset of dimensions, with the `start_dim` and `end_dim` arguments.

---

1. Actually the superficially equivalent [`reshape`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57241451/9067615) under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `.view()` works only on [contiguous data](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-contiguous-and-noncontiguous-memory-allocation/), while `.flatten()` works on both *contiguous* and *non contiguous data*. Functions like [transpose](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html) whcih generates *non-contiguous data*, can be acted upon by `.flatten()` but not `.view()`.
Coming to copying of data, both `.view()` and `.flatten()` does not copy data when it works on *contiguous data*. However, in case of *non-contiguous data*, `.flatten()` first copies data  into *contiguous memory* and then change the dimensions. Any change in the new tensor would not affect th original tensor.

```
 ten=torch.zeros(2,3)
 ten_view=ten.view(-1)
 ten_view[0]=123
 ten 

>>tensor([[123.,   0.,   0.],
           [  0.,   0.,   0.]])

 ten=torch.zeros(2,3)
 ten_flat=ten.flatten()
 ten_flat[0]=123
 ten

>>tensor([[123.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

In the above code, the tensor *ten* have contiguous memory allocation. Any changes to *ten_view* or *ten_flat* is reflected upon tensor *ten*

```
ten=torch.zeros(2,3).transpose(0,1)
ten_flat=ten.flatten()
ten_flat[0]=123
ten

>>tensor([[0., 0.],
        [0., 0.],
        [0., 0.]])
```

In this case non-contiguous transposed tensor *ten* is used for flatten(). Any changes made to *ten_flat* is not reflected upon *ten*.