# PyTorch: .movedim() vs. .moveaxis() vs. .permute()

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I'm completely new to PyTorch, and I was wondering if there's anything I'm missing when it comes to the `.moveaxis()` and `.movedim()` methods. The outputs are the exact same for the same arguments. Also can't both of these methods be replaced by `.permute()`?

An example for reference:

```
import torch

mytensor = torch.randn(3,6,3,1,7,21,4)

t_md = torch.movedim(mytensor, 2, 5)
t_ma = torch.moveaxis(mytensor, 2, 5)

print(t_md.shape, t_ma.shape)
print(torch.allclose(t_md, t_ma))

t_p = torch.permute(mytensor, (0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 6))

print(t_p.shape)
print(torch.allclose(t_md, t_p))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `moveaxis` is an alias of `movedim` (analogous to [`swapaxes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66985153/9067615) and `swapdims`).<sup>1</sup>

Yes, this functionality can be achieved with `permute`, but moving one axis while keeping the relative positions of all others is a [common enough use-case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67286845/9067615) to warrant its own syntactic sugar.

---

1. The terminology is taken from [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html):

   > Alias for `torch.movedim()`.
   >
   > This function is equivalent to NumPy’s moveaxis function.