# RuntimeError when execute torch.matmul()

Tags: runtime-error, pytorch

I’m trying to implement an attention model, but fail to execute the matmul

```
torch.matmul(att, v)
```

The shape of att and v is:

```
att shape:torch.Size([20, 3, 128, 128])
v shape:torch.Size([20, 3, 128, 100])
```

i get such an error:

> RuntimeError: Expected tensor to have size 100 at dimension 1, but got size 128 for argument #2 ‘batch2’ (while checking arguments for bmm)

I also tried generate two tensors with the same shape by torch.randn and repeat the same operation and no error ouccrred. I don’t know what makes such an error

Comment: PyTorch version? Cannot reproduce on `1.4.1`

Comment: I train my model on a server with pytorch version 1.3.0. And i test using torch.randn() on my own laptop, of which pytorch version is 1.3.1

Comment: I run my test script on the server and no error occurred, it seems that a previous step causes it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Discrepancy of align on memory and shape.If you use view method, you can handle tensor shape as you want. But array on memory is not reshaped. This sometimes causes unclear problem. So contiguous() or reshape() may help you.

ref:
https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html?highlight=view#torch.Tensor.view
[What's the difference between reshape and view in pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643225/whats-the-difference-between-reshape-and-view-in-pytorch)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried both methods but they don't work.