# Pytorch: after embedding layer, Unable to get repr for <class 'torch.Tensor'>

Tags: python, pytorch, embedding

I am new to PyTorch and trying to reproduce the project: https://github.com/eXascaleInfolab/ActiveLink

However, errors occur in the `feedforward()` which has been bothering me for days, here is part of the code (for complete code of the model, see https://github.com/eXascaleInfolab/ActiveLink/blob/master/models.py please):

```
def forward(self, e1, rel, batch_size=None, weights=None):
......
        e1_embedded = self.emb_e(e1).view(-1, 1, 10, 20)
        rel_embedded = self.emb_rel(rel).view(-1, 1, 10, 20)
        stacked_inputs = torch.cat([e1_embedded, rel_embedded], 2)  # out: (128L, 1L, 20L, 20L)
```

That gives me the error (I am using GPU):

```
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/pytorch/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMath.cu line=196 error=710 : device-side assert triggered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 147, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 136, in main
    model = run_meta_incremental(config, model, train_batcher, test_rank_batcher)
  File "/home/yonghui/yt/meta_incr_training.py", line 158, in run_meta_incremental
    g = run_inner(config, model, task)
  File "/home/yonghui/yt/meta_incr_training.py", line 120, in run_inner
    pred = model.forward(e1, rel)
  File "/home/yonghui/yt/models.py", line 136, in forward
    stacked_inputs = torch.cat([e1_embedded, rel_embedded], 2)
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (710) : device-side assert triggered at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMath.cu:196
/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:361: void indexSelectLargeIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim = 2, SrcDim = 2, IdxDim = -2, IndexIsMajor = true]: block: [189,0,0], thread: [0,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:361: void indexSelectLargeIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim = 2, SrcDim = 2, IdxDim = -2, IndexIsMajor = true]: block: [189,0,0], thread: [1,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:361: void indexSelectLargeIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim = 2, SrcDim = 2, IdxDim = -2, IndexIsMajor = true]: block: [189,0,0], thread: [2,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:361: void indexSelectLargeIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim = 2, SrcDim = 2, IdxDim = -2, IndexIsMajor = true]: block: [189,0,0], thread: [3,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:361: void indexSelectLargeIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim = 2, SrcDim = 2, IdxDim = -2, IndexIsMajor = true]: block: [189,0,0], thread: [4,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:361: void indexSelectLargeIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim = 2, SrcDim = 2, IdxDim = -2, IndexIsMajor = true]: block: [189,0,0], thread: [5,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:361: void indexSelectLargeIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim = 2, SrcDim = 2, IdxDim = -2, IndexIsMajor = true]: block: [189,0,0], thread: [6,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCTensorIndex.cu:361: void indexSelectLargeIndex(TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<T, IndexType>, TensorInfo<long, IndexType>, int, int, IndexType, IndexType, long) [with T = float, IndexType = unsigned int, DstDim = 2, SrcDim = 2, IdxDim = -2, IndexIsMajor = true]: block: [189,0,0], thread: [7,0,0] Assertion `srcIndex < srcSelectDimSize` failed.
```

I use Debugger in an attempt to find out where goes wrong:
Before `e1` and `rel` are embedded, they are both tensors in `int64` with the shape of `torch.Size([128, 1])`.

`e1` can be embedded as normal, converting into `torch.float32` and `torch.Size([128, 1, 10, 20])`. However, after `rel` passed the embedding layer of `emb_rel`, Debugger shows all tenros as `Unable to get repr for <class 'torch.Tensor'>`.

What's going on? How can I fix that? Thank you for any possible help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved by using the debugger and checking the input tensor.

After checking the tensors before embedding, I find that some elements exceed the range, especially for the case where the index starting from 0.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is somewhere before this error message gets printed, probably in the reshaping.

Calling view does not change the underlying data, it only changes the "view" of them and does that lazily. If the different view of the tensor is not possible (e.g., because the tensor is not contiguously stored in the memory, cf. [PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/contigious-vs-non-contigious-tensor/30107/2)), it fails at the first occasion when the content of the tensor should be used, in your case when you want to debug-print the tensor.

For debugging, consider replacing `view` with `reshape` (cf., [StackOverflow thread on the difference between view and reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643225/whats-the-difference-between-reshape-and-view-in-pytorch)).

Comment: Thank you for such information:)  but the error doesn't change after I changed `view` to `reshape`

Comment: Okay, then I suggest you should try what is the last tensor you are able to print. This should be the moment then immediately precedes your bug.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I also tried converting it to CPU version, where the debugger info is much more intuitive, saying the index out of its range in embedding layer. Thank you for the help again. :)