# Pytorch view vs unsqueeze when adding a dummy dimension?

Tags: pytorch

I have a pytorch tensor that has shape `[n1, n2, n3]`. I need to make the shape `[n1, n2, n3, 1]`.

So I know I can use either unsqueeze or view. Is there a difference in what each one would do in this case?

Comment: Well the main difference is that view is closer to reshape the entire array, while unsqueeze is just a appending an extra dimension onto the array. But at the end you can use both to achieve the same effect

Comment: Not sure about the performance difference though but usually for simplicity best to use unsqueeze if ur just adding an extra dimension

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with four different solutions. There are slight differences between those. More precisely you can:

- insert a new singleton dimension with [`torch.Tensor.unqueeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.unsqueeze.html):

  ```
  >>> x.unsqueeze(-1) # grad_fn=<UnsqueezeBackward0>
  ```
- use fancy indexing to add a new dimension which is identical:

  ```
  >>> x[..., None] # grad_fn=<UnsqueezeBackward0>
  ```
- or similarly with [`torch.Tensor.view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html):

  ```
  >>> x.view(*x.shape, 1) # grad_fn=<ViewBackward0>
  ```
- add a new dimension with [`torch.Tensor.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html):

  ```
  >>> x.reshape(*x.shape, 1) # grad_fn=<ReshapeAliasBackward0>
  ```

I have added the backward gradient function name as a line comment next to each method. You can see how indexing and unsqueezing are the same, while `view` and reshape rely on two different methods.

All three methods: indexing, `unsqueeze`, and `view` will return a `view` of the tensor while `reshape` *can* return a copy of the tensor *if needed* (*i.e.* when the data is not contiguous).

You can read more about the differences between `torch.view` and `torch.reshape` on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643225/whats-the-difference-between-reshape-and-view-in-pytorch).