# How to reshape and change the rank of a numpy array?

Tags: numpy

if  I have a numpy array of shape

`(16, 224, 224, 6)`

how can I reshape it to

`(224, 224, 6*16)`

so that all elements are still in the new shape?
P.S.:I need a numpy answer and not an answere derived from pytorch please :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pytorch reshape tensor dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328632/pytorch-reshape-tensor-dimension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use `transpose` and `reshape`:

```
a.transpose([1,2,3,0]).reshape(244,244,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most elegant and easy to understand way is to use `einops`:

```py
from einops import rearrange
a = rearrange(a, 'b w h c -> w h (b c)')
```

Plus this code works on Numpy, Pytorch, Jax and Tensorflow without changes.