# How are dimensions handled in pytorch's tensors?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

How does the `size` parameter behave in creation of tensors?
How does the `axis` parameter behave in methods like `torch.Tensor.sum()` and `torch.Tensor.softmax()`?

I would like to give a good overview of how `pytorch.Tensor` instances in handle dimensions, both in creation and aggregation.

*Note: I have seen posts explaining some aspects of this, like [reshaping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43328632/pytorch-reshape-tensor-dimension). I would like to give a more fundamental explanation, such as I would have expected to find on the [official pytorch-docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/index.html), but couldn't find. All other explanations I have found were hosted on Medium and similar sites.*

Answer (score 0):

## Tensor creation

When creating tensors, pytorch accepts a tuple as for the size argument:

```
# can be abbreviated:
torch.ones((2,3))
torch.ones(2,3)
# can not be abbreviated:
torch.randint(10, (2,3))
```

This `size` argument specified the dimensionalities **from last to to first element**, such that the last element in the tuple always denotes the number of columns in the resulting vector, the second-to-last element in the tuple always denotes the number of rows, and so on.

```
# size=(..., m, n)
# n columns
# m rows
# ...
```

Some examples:

| size | description | columns | rows | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `(2,)` | [row vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_and_column_vectors) of length 2; does not have a second dimension | 2 | - | - |
| `(2,1)` | matrix; might look like a column vector, but has two dimensions | 1 | 2 | - |
| `(1,2)` | matrix; might look like a row vector, but has two dimensions | 2 | 1 | - |
| `(3,2)` | matrix | 2 | 3 | - |
| `(4,3,2)` | tensor ("3D-matrix") | 2 | 3 | 4 |

## Tensor Aggregation

Many methods of the `pytorch.Tensor`-class require an `axis`-argument (usually: `int` or `list of int`). The operation in question is then applied **along** the specified axis. For tensors of `1`s (created as `torch.ones(size)`), this means that the operation `torch.sum(axis=axis)` does the following:

| size | axis | output shape | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `(2,)` | `-1` or `0` | `[]` | `tensor(2.)` |
| `(2,1)` | `-1` or `1` | `[2]` | `tensor([1., 1.])` |
| `(1,2)` | `-1` or `1` | `[1]` | `tensor([2.])` |
| `(3,2)` | `-1` or `1` | `[3]` | `tensor([2., 2., 2.])` |
| `(4,3,2)` | `-1` or `2` | `[4,3]` | `tensor([[2., 2., 2.],[2., 2., 2.],[2., 2., 2.],[2., 2., 2.]])` |

It becomes clear that `torch.sum(axis=-1)` always does two things:

1. **It sums all element along the column-axis.** For a row-vector (tensor of dimensionality 1), the result is thus a number which is the sum of all the vector's elements; for a matrix with just one column, since there is only one row, the sum is equal to the matrix's original values; for a matrix with just one row, the result is a one-dimensional vector of size 1 whose only element is the sum of all elements in the matrix; and for higher-dimensional matrices and tensors, the sum happens "across each row", when you take into account the standard display of the tensor.
2. **It reduces the dimensionality and "moves" every axis**. The last axis vanishes, and its place is taken by the second-to-last axis, whose place is taken by the third-to-last axis, and so on. This can be confusing, since pytorch seems to "rotate" the resulting matrices, but this behavious is because the last dimension in a tensor is always the number of columns and displayed as such.

Behaviour is similar for other specifications of the `axis`-argument.

## Tensor transformation

In tensor transformation, the shape of the original tensor is preserved, but its values are changed. Take `torch.softmax()` as an example: [softmax transforms the values so that their sum equals one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function). The `dim` argument lets you choose along which axis the sum of elements equals 1:

```
# for dim=-1, the sums along the columns equal one:
torch.randn((2,2,2)).softmax(dim=-1)
>>> tensor([[[0.7512, 0.2488],
             [0.1585, 0.8415]],
    
            [[0.5132, 0.4868],
             [0.5440, 0.4560]]])
# for dim=-2, the sums along the rows equal one:
>>>> tensor([[[0.8773, 0.3083],
              [0.1227, 0.6917]],

             [[0.2968, 0.3233],
              [0.7032, 0.6767]]])
```